# Automated creation of self executing Python code

Tags: python, automation

For my PhD I am currently working on a problem where I have to create a Python program which takes a predefined list of code snippets and glues them together following a set of rules. This code should then be called and executed automatically as well. The best solution I think of so far is the following:

1. Use the default Python file writer interface to save the glued snippets into
2. Save the file with automatically generated name
3. Call this automatically generated name from the original program

While this would probably work it seems quite unelegant to me. Is there a better way to do this? Also is there a technical term associated with this kind of problem?

Comment: You can use `eval` and `exec` to directly execute strings of Python code, no need to write it to a file first.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But does this also work for quite long code that is to be created and executed? In my case the automatically generated code is meant to create and calibrate and hydrological model and could be a couple of 100 lines long.

Comment: A few hundred lines is nothing.  Even if you did write the code to a file, it would be read entirely into memory, and then have the exact equivalent of `exec` applied to it.

Comment: Alright thanks. But how does one handle things like indentation within the code snippets? Do I have to prepare the snippets for all possible cases of indentation seperately or is there are more convenient way? And is there a package or something similar with which the glueing could be handled?